# "I'll be there in around one hour" or "I'll be there in one hour around"

Tags: adverbs, grammaticality-in-context

I want to say that I'm going to be there in one hours but it's approximately not accurate. What's the best way to say it? How to locate the adverb (around) in this sentence?

> "I'll be there in **around** one hour."

or

> "I'll be there in one hour **around**."

Or maybe other way to say it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely "I'll be there in around one hour". You could also replace around with **about** or, to sound more technical, **approximately**, or even **roughly**.

If you choose *approximately* or *roughly*, they *can* go after the "one hour". You should use a comma after the 'hour' in the case of 'roughly', and can use a comma or not in the case of 'approximately'.

You could also use **or thereabouts**, at least in British English, after 'one hour'. That one can even be combined with any of the options that go in front of the length of time to add some redundant uncertainty, which can help to emphasise how uncertain you are.